# combining user owned objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a question and answer forum on rails 4.1 with a react client where the user can create questions, answers, and comments. I want to pass all the user activity (regardless of type) using active model serializers. Ideally this should be an array of objects sorted by created_at. I'm able to create the array, but the push methods overwrite one another.

I feel like I might need to actually use a hash to avoid a labyrinth of working with an attribute nested inside the individual object arrays, but hoping for a little guidance.

If this doesn't make sense, think about Facebook showing you your recent activity:

```
[
  "You posted 'It's my birthday!' on 08/04/2017", 
  "You liked Tammy's post on 8/3/2017", 
  "You commented on Rihanna Tweets as Motivational Posters page on 8/1/2017"
]
```

user_activity method:

```
def user_activity
  activity = []

  self.object.questions.each do |question|
    activity.push(question)
  end

  self.object.answers.each do |answer|
    activity.push(answer)
  end

  self.object.comments.each do |comment|
    activity.push(comment)
  end

end
```

Thanks and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: your `user_activity` must return the `activity` array at the end -- Also, I think using AM::Serializer is overkill in your case since you just want to output a string (and not serialize a record into a specific object, like a Hash). A simple module included in every Model needing this user-activity-compatible (= a string) output would be enough. I can provide an example on how to achieve this

Comment: Woot! Thanks @MrYoshiji. I knew it was something dumb I was forgetting. Worked as expected! Thanks!

Comment: I think we're married to AMS at this point, but I wouldn't mind the extra information. We are actually serializing a lot of records in the non-user objects.

Answer (score 0):

Module implementation:

```
module UserActivityOutputer
  def output_for_user_activity
    raise NotImplementedError, "You must implement `#{self.class}##{__method__}`"
  end
end
```

Module inclusion:

```
class Post
  include UserActivityOutputer
  def title ; 'combining user owned objects in rails' ; end # only here for easy copy-paste test in IRB
  def created_at ; DateTime.now ; end # only here for easy copy-paste test in IRB

  def output_for_user_activity
    "You posted '#{self.title}' on #{I18n.l(self.created_at.to_date)}"
  end
end

class SomeModel
  include UserActivityOutputer
  # did not implement output_for_user_activity method for example purpose
end
```

Usage:

```
Post.new.output_for_user_activity
# => "You posted 'combining user owned objects in rails' on 2017-08-09"
SomeModel.new.output_for_user_activity
# => NotImplementedError: You must implement `SomeModel#output_for_user_activity`
```

You can copy-paste all of the code presented here in a freshly opened IRB console (might redefine existing `Post` or `SomeModel` class) and see the output.

This is a very basic implementation only meant to define *"what should be output for this record"*. It does not support the sorting, which would be made somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed. Just curious why you prefer this over using AMS. We're passing everything else through a serializer, and only have use for this "activity list" in the client. It won't be persisted as a separate column on the user model or anything like that.